# Canvas stretching instead of cropping and start position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I got a canvas with some falling confetti in it and I change its height onscroll with this jquery:

```
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function () {
    $('#world').toggleClass('tiny', $(document).scrollTop() > 0);
});
```

But the canvas just get strechted instead of cropped and so the confetti look weird. 
That are my confetti:

```
(function() {
  var COLORS, Confetti, NUM_CONFETTI, PI_2, canvas, confetti, context, drawCircle, i, range, resizeWindow, xpos;

  NUM_CONFETTI = 350;
  COLORS = [[85, 71, 106], [174, 61, 99], [219, 56, 83], [244, 92, 68], [248, 182, 70]];
  PI_2 = 2 * Math.PI;
  canvas = document.getElementById("world");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  window.w = 0;
  window.h = 0;
  resizeWindow = function() {
    window.w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    return window.h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  };
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeWindow, false);
  window.onload = function() {
    return setTimeout(resizeWindow, 0);
  };
  range = function(a, b) {
    return (b - a) * Math.random() + a;
  };
  drawCircle = function(x, y, r, style) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, r, 0, PI_2, false);
    context.fillStyle = style;
    return context.fill();
  };
  xpos = 0.5;
  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    return xpos = e.pageX / w;
  };
  window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
      return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
  })();
  Confetti = (function() {
    function Confetti() {
      this.style = COLORS[~~range(0, 5)];
      this.rgb = "rgba(" + this.style[0] + "," + this.style[1] + "," + this.style[2];
      this.r = ~~range(2, 6);
      this.r2 = 2 * this.r;
      this.replace();
    }
    Confetti.prototype.replace = function() {
      this.opacity = 0;
      this.dop = 0.03 * range(1, 4);
      this.x = range(-this.r2, w - this.r2);
      this.y = range(-20, h - this.r2);
      this.xmax = w - this.r;
      this.ymax = h - this.r;
      this.vx = range(0, 2) + 8 * xpos - 5;
      return this.vy = 0.7 * this.r + range(-1, 1);
    };
    Confetti.prototype.draw = function() {
      var ref;
      this.x += this.vx;
      this.y += this.vy;
      this.opacity += this.dop;
      if (this.opacity > 1) {
        this.opacity = 1;
        this.dop *= -1;
      }
      if (this.opacity < 0 || this.y > this.ymax) {
        this.replace();
      }
      if (!((0 < (ref = this.x) && ref < this.xmax))) {
        this.x = (this.x + this.xmax) % this.xmax;
      }
      return drawCircle(~~this.x, ~~this.y, this.r, this.rgb + "," + this.opacity + ")");
    };
    return Confetti;
  })();
  confetti = (function() {
    var j, ref, results;
    results = [];
    for (i = j = 1, ref = NUM_CONFETTI; 1 <= ref ? j <= ref : j >= ref; i = 1 <= ref ? ++j : --j) {
      results.push(new Confetti);
    }
    return results;
  })();
  window.step = function() {
    var c, j, len, results;
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    results = [];
    for (j = 0, len = confetti.length; j < len; j++) {
      c = confetti[j];
      results.push(c.draw());
    }
    return results;
  };
  step();
}).call(this);
```

And the other problem is that the confetti start falling from the top. But I'd like that they already fill the whole canvas. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while your canvas is trying to detect a `window.resize` event, the animation doesn't change the window's size. Instead it just shrinks the wrapper of the canvas, which makes the animation weird. I think what you have to do is to add `overflow: hidden;` to the CSS of the container of the canvas, so that when it changes size, the canvas inside can retain its size (by having `height: __px;` rule on the canvas).

Hopefully this helps: [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/CharCoding/2kLdonva/)

You can probably delete the listener for `window.resize`.

**EDIT** - `overflow: hidden;` doesn't work:

Simply remove the rules `position: fixed;` and `height: 100%;` from the canvas. On page load the canvas already resizes to the correct size and stays in the correct position. A fix-positioned element will be displayed over a statically positioned element. Remove the two styles and everything should work like in the JSFiddle.